# GET request parameters to case class in Play & Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have inherited 2 controller methods (for GET requests) that accept the same 10 request parameters like so:

```
class Application @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def func1(param1: String,
            param2: String,
            param3: String
              ...
            param10: String
           ) = Action {
      ...
  }

  def func2(param1: String,
            param2: String,
            param3: String
              ...
            param10: String
           ) = Action {
      ...
  }

}
```

These are mapped like so:

```
GET           /f1                      blah.blah.Application.func1(p1: String, p2: String...p10: String)
GET           /f2                      blah.blah.Application.func2(p1: String, p2: String...p10: String)
```

I like to avoid the repetition. I am wondering if it is possible to define a case class with 10 fields named after the request parameters, have the controller methods accept one parameter of the case-class-type and have Play match request parameter names to field names and bind the value?

This can be easily achieved if the same values were submitted in a POST request body. But this is not an option as this end-point has been exposed to clients.

Comment: You are looking for [query string binders](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRequestBinders#querystringbindable). Note that you need to import them to routes, in your `build.sbt`, like `routesImport += "utils.MyBinders._"`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! If you would like to post it as an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Query string binders](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRequestBinders#querystringbindable) are used for that. Basically, you tell Play how to parse the parameters, group them to a class and reverse (turn them back to String representation). Let's say you want a `Page` abstraction:

```
case class Page(from: Int, to: Int)

implicit def pageQSB(implicit intBinder: QueryStringBindable[Int]) = new QueryStringBindable[Page] {
  override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, Page]] = {
    for {
      from <- intBinder.bind("from", params)
      to <- intBinder.bind("to", params)
    } yield {
      (from, to) match {
        case (Right(from), Right(to)) => Right(Page(from, to))
        case _ => Left("Unable to bind a Page")
      }
    }
  }
  override def unbind(key: String, page: Page): String = {
    intBinder.unbind("from", page.from) + "&" + intBinder.unbind("to", page.to)
  }
}
```

Note that you have to import these implicits to routes scope (in your build.sbt), e.g.

```
routesImport += "utils.MyBinders._"
```

Comment: this doesn't compile, returns `wrong top statement declaration`...